# Access MDC in aspect when uploading multipart in spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-aop, mdc

Hello Im using spring boot 3 and spring webflux and micrometer package for tracing in app

my dependency for tracing using micrometer:

```
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
implementation 'io.micrometer:context-propagation:latest.integration'
```

I also add `Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();` to main method to access MDC and  restore the **ThreadLocal** I always work but when I want to call api for uploading multipart data I can not access MDC keys .
I think it happens because uploading file is blocking request and it schedule it to another thread

My log aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogAop {
    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void controllerPointCut() {
    }

    @Before(value = "controllerPointCut()")
    public void logAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("signature:{}, args:{}", joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString(), joinPoint.getArgs());
    }
}
```

```
2023-07-19T12:53:29.842+04:30  INFO [                                ,                 ] 19064 --- [or-http-epoll-3] ir.zarebin.profile.aspects.LogAop        : signature:ProfileController.update(..), args:[ab8a8daf-d4f9-4777-b54b-682f0326ceea, ProfileIn[displayName=fuckboy, username=asdssad, image=file:test.jpg], DefaultFilePart{file (test.jpg)}]
```

As you see It cant log traceId but after change thread It can access traceId.

```
2023-07-19T12:53:31.895+04:30  INFO [64b79d810a5369e8ec79c012fa6299a1, ec79c012fa6299a1] 19064 --- [nc-response-1-1] i.z.p.services.impl.CephFileService      : [I198] creating BytBuffer from 1 chunks
2023-07-19T12:53:31.896+04:30  INFO [64b79d810a5369e8ec79c012fa6299a1, ec79c012fa6299a1] 19064 --- [nc-response-1-1] i.z.p.services.impl.CephFileService      : [I208] partData: size=45380
```

my controller for upload file:

```
    public Mono<ProfileOut> update(@RequestParam UUID userId,
                                   @RequestPart("data") @Valid ProfileIn body,
                                   @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) FilePart image) {
       return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> {
                   ContextSnapshotFactory.builder().contextRegistry(ContextRegistry.getInstance().loadThreadLocalAccessors())
                           .build().captureAll();

                    return Mono.just(contextView);
                })
                .flatMap(o -> service.update(userId, body, image));
    }
```

How can I access traceId when I need?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: In particular, you are presenting an aspect without the target class it is meant to intercept. You also talk about MDC, thread-locals and Micrometer, but none of the code related to those is visible here. Unfortunately, that means: Without any magical crystal globe, probably nobondy will be able to help you.

Comment: By Adding `implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'` we will have traceId But when we want to upload file we can not access to traceId

Comment: target class for aspect is controller witch contains rest apis